Why is my 15 months old waking in the night screaming and staying awake for 1.5 hours
Our 15 month old has never been a great sleeper but 2 months ago she started waking in the night screaming - sounds like in pain or scared. She cannot be easily calmed down but when she is she tries to get back to sleep but she fidgets and moves so much it takes about 1.5 hours.
To cope we have started sleeping next to her but we know this isn’t a great idea. We want to get back to sleep training again but are worried about what is causing it and what is best to do.
Has anyone experienced this? Worked out what it is? Ideas of what to do?
Thank you!

Can you notice it ahead? If so, would some comforting while she's just asleep help? My kid sometimes has a nightmare, when we're at it quick enough and give him a slow, light, comforting backrub he often calms down.

Does the child really wake up or do they scream in their sleep ? I am verifying, since there is a difference between nightmares and night terrors - both may emerge at this age. Nightmares are more likely in the morning, since they occur in the light phase of sleep, while the terrors take place in deep sleep.
